# Read a tree from a .root file and then make zero padded .h5 file

Tags: uproot

I have a .root file containing a tree named FlatSubstructureJetTreeD
file = uproot.open("/data/debo/jetAnomaly/AtlasData/dijets/mergedRoot/miniTrees/user.cdelitzs.JZ2W.mini.root")["FlatSubstructureJetTreeD"]

It has the following branches

file.keys()
['fjet_pt',
 'fjet_clus_P',
 'fjet_clus_px',
 'fjet_clus_py',
 'fjet_clus_pz',
 'EventInfo_mcEventWeight',
 'fjet_xsec_filteff_numevents']

fjet_clus_P,fjet_clus_px,fjet_clus_py,fjet_clus_pz are jagged array (different entries in different events)

I need to make a zero-padded dataset as a form of .h5 file so that each row has entries in format of [fjet_clus_P1,fjet_clus_px1,fjet_clus_py1,fjet_clus_pz1,fjet_clus_P2,fjet_clus_px2,fjet_clus_py2,fjet_clus_pz2,....,fjet_clus_Pn,fjet_clus_pxn,fjet_clus_pyn,fjet_clus_pzn], could you suggest what would be the smartest and memory-efficient way to do so in uproot?

Thanks,
Debo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have read out all of the arrays as a dict named `arrays`,

```py
import uproot
file = uproot.open("/data/debo/jetAnomaly/AtlasData/dijets/mergedRoot/"
            "miniTrees/user.cdelitzs.JZ2W.mini.root"
           )["FlatSubstructureJetTreeD"]
arrays = file.arrays(["fjet_clus_P", "fjet_clus_px", "fjet_clus_py",
                      "fjet_clus_pz"], namedecode="utf-8")
```

You can `None`-pad each array with the `pad` method and then turn the `None` values into zeros with `fillna`. In `pad`, you have to specify a length; let's take the maximum length per event. After this operation, the `JaggedArrays` happen to have equal lengths in the second dimension, so turn them into NumPy arrays with `regular`.

```py
for name in arrays:
    longest = arrays[name].counts.max()
    arrays[name] = arrays[name].pad(longest).fillna(0).regular()
```

Now that they're (two-dimensional) NumPy arrays, [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html) will recognize them and you can write them to the HDF5 file the normal way.

**Edit:** And if you want all the data in a contiguous block array, you'll have to choose a single `longest` length, preallocate the block, and fill it. (The call to `regular` ought to be optional now, but check.)

```py
longest = 2
for name in arrays:
    arrays[name] = arrays[name].pad(longest).fillna(0)

output = numpy.empty(file.numentries,
                     dtype=[("px1", "f8"), ("py1", "f8"), ("pz1", "f8"),
                            ("px2", "f8"), ("py2", "f8"), ("pz2", "f8")])
output["px1"] = arrays["fjet_clus_px"][:, 0]
output["py1"] = arrays["fjet_clus_py"][:, 0]
output["py1"] = arrays["fjet_clus_pz"][:, 0]
output["px2"] = arrays["fjet_clus_px"][:, 1]
output["py2"] = arrays["fjet_clus_py"][:, 1]
output["py2"] = arrays["fjet_clus_pz"][:, 1]
```

This is vectorized (i.e. no Python for loops, implicit or explicit). Even if you write a loop over all column names, there's only 10-ish columns, but probably millions or billions of rows.

Comment: Thanks, But I need a little modification because the way you suggested fo each row it will first keep all Ps then all pxs, all pys and pzs respectively but I want to have an array with each row as P1,px1,py1,pz1,P2,px2,py2,pz2,....,Pn,pxn,pyn,pzn so if I write a loop it would be,

`for i in range (0,P.shape)

for j in range (0,P[i].shape)

   write in 2D array P[i,j],px[i,j],py[i,j],pz[i,j]`
Is there a way in uproot where I can do it without making a for loop I mean in a vectorized way?

Thanks, Debo.

shareeditdeleteflag

Comment: Hi @jim for some root file I am getting memory error arrays[name] = arrays[name].pad(longest).fillna(0).regular()
  File "/home/debo/env_autoencoder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awkward/array/jagged.py", line 1876, in pad
    content = self._content[index]
MemoryError, Do  you have any suggestion to make it memory efficient like making it chunk by chunk

Comment: Yes: instead of calling `file.arrays` and doing everything once, call `file.iterate` in a loop. See the [uproot README](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot#readme) for examples.